# Accessing a "forgotten" Google scholar account

Tags: google-scholar

I have a Google scholar [account A](https://scholar.google.si/citations?user=gty0SkUAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=ao) which is linked to my Google account and it all works well. But there is also another copy of me, a Google scholar [account B](https://scholar.google.si/citations?user=u7JW7bIAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=ao), which says that it has a "verified email" (which is my university email). Apparently, I must have confirmed it some time in the past.

How do I access account B? I cannot access it through my Google account, which just takes me to account A. Is there some way to make it send an email to my university address that will let me access it?

Comment: Have you asked Google?

Comment: How? I googled around quite a bit, if that's your asking. You can't seriously expect me to reach a Google humanoid?

Comment: I'd try to reach the humanoid, yes.

Comment: @keshlam humans at Google are usually exceptionally hard to reach, unless you happen to know one personally.

Comment: @SimonW When one is logged into their Google Scholar account, there is a standard "contact form" under settings->provide feedback. This would be my first choice if I had to reach a humanoid. Have you tried using that? Do you claim it doesn't work?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I haven't used it, but based on more general experience with Google I would expect "provide feedback" to be a one-way process, and the odds of getting a reply to be low.

Comment: @SimonW I've contacted Google many times and always found them polite and helpful. I did have one interaction that took a few days to resolve, but they kept me informed all along the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found an answer: think hard about whether there are other Google accounts that I might have and through which I could have authorized the Scholar account.

In my case, there is a long forgotten "temporary" Google account which was created for me by Goolge during that period when they decided to merge all of its services under the Goolge+ umbrella.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following sequence in order to generate an email to your university address:

1. Sign out of Google.
2. Navigate to Google Scholar.
3. Click "sign in" in the top right corner
4. On the log in page, click "Need help?" in small font just below the "Next" button.
5. Select "I'm having other problems signing in."
6. Enter your university email address to which Account B is associated.

Comment: I tried that already, I should have said it. The reply is "no such account". I wonder how I managed to "verify email". It may be useful to know that my gmail account is associated with my university account. That is, when I send email from gmail I can select my university email as the `From:` field. This is so because  a while ago I confirmed with google that I actually own the university email account.