# Accessing a Google Scholar profile when I do not remember the e-mail account I used to create it

Tags: google-scholar

I have a scholar profile, but I do not remember the Gmail account with which I created it. Therefore, I cannot add publications to or correct errors in the profile.
I have created another account with another profile, but before completing it, I want to know if it is possible to delete the first profile, or if there is any way to know the Gmail account with which I created the first profile in order to update it. Thank you very much.

Comment: maybe related http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55400/accessing-a-forgotten-google-scholar-account

Comment: Seems like a question for Google -- have you tried contacting them?

Comment: The problem is that in such forum entry the options have changed since the interface is no longer the same. could anybody tell me how to get in contact with them?

Comment: Please, any help?