# How can I remove a verified google-scholar account?

Tags: google-scholar

I have moved to another university and created a new google scholar account here. However, my old account which was verified with the academic email address of the former university still shows up. I am no longer at my old university so I CAN'T LOGIN to that old account in order to delete it. I tried to remove that verified google scholar, but I could not. I also contacted google scholar via google scholar support email, that is ‘scholar-support@google.com’ but nobody answered me.

So, I'm wondering how to delete that old account?

Comment: Contact google scholar, why do you think we are google scholar help?

Comment: a simple search on here gives : https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55400/72855

Comment: @SolarMike _"I also contacted google scholar via google scholar support email, that is ‘scholar-support@google.com’ but nobody answered me."_ Many of us also are people who have used Google Scholar and may be able to help.

Comment: @SolarMike There's little chance to contact Google and get to talk to an actual human.

Comment: @JiK “many of us also are people” or “many of us are also people”?

Answer (score 3):

Deletion of the entire linked Google account worked in my case.

I used to have a Google Scholar profile through a Google account at a corporation but when they (unwillingly) deleted my account, the Google Scholar automatically got deleted. Considering Google did not get back to you, it might be worthwhile to get in touch with your old university to see if they could permanently delete your account.